# Turning 2D Front and Side View Images into a 3D Object

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been trying to look for a method from a program I tried around the years 2000 - 2004 in which there was a tutorial I found that explained and showed how to take 2D front and side view drawings placed on the x and y axis so as to be able to extrude, pull, sculpt, and form a cube or sphere into the shape of the drawing that you were trying to create. Said tutorial had a dragon side and front view drawings to go with it if that helps any.

I was unable to find that specific tutorial or at least one like it that I was wanting to mimic in Blender and was hoping if anyone remembered something similar or had link(s) to that type of tutorial or for a way to do something like it in blender?

Answer (score 0):

I did find some useful techniques/methods/programs over the years that were just as good with using one or several background images. Such as the following:

1 - Extruding a simple mesh or vector graphic in a 2D or isometric view. Though you might need a blender add-on for the isometric view.
2 - Smoothie-3D, One 2D picture to create model from, then import into Blender.
3 - Regard 3D, by using multiple views to create a model and bring into Blender.
4 - Kinect with 3D Scan app, then work on your file in Blender.
5 - 3Sweep, though you'll have to check when it'll be commercially available to the public and by then you can use Blender to flesh out any issues.
6 - PhotoAnim 3D, you can use one 2D image to work from. Then work on refining it in Blender where needed.
7 - ZBrush, Use their Concept Sculpting method. Which you could go back and forth between ZBrush and Blender where needed depending on your work method.
8 - Use Blender to set your layout to look about the same as in the following video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nGpRn1akSY or this image https://i.ytimg.com/vi/bqjaWGVfRj8/maxresdefault.jpg to be able to develop/create your mesh to the shape you need.

If the links for #8 ever disappear, think of the layout(s) as a split view for x and y for the front and side or with a z for the top down view, plus maybe a 4th view that has the camera angled to see a decent 3D view of the item as a whole.

As for the technique I was looking for, it was along the lines of the "ZBrush - Concept Sculpting" method; but using the lines and shape of the two drawings as guidelines for the pen, inflate, deflate and grab tools to transform your 2D drawing on a plane or cube into the 3D object you wanted.

Hope this info helps those that are trying to turn their 2D drawings into a 3D object.

If you have a better method or know of the tutorial I mentioned in the question let me know.

Comment: The usual method is to add reference images in both front and side view and work from them. [Here's a YT video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-49fRP1Y5TI)  showing how to set up and use them.